# MySQL Query Not Working - No Errors

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my query isn't working, I'll post the code and output of $_POST.

I will also add a screenshot for the structure of the database.

$_POST: [image]

Code:

```
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "lunar_casino", "******", "lunar_casino");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $error = array();
      if(empty($error)){
        $bonus = $_POST['bonus'];
        $deposit = $_POST['deposit'];
        $offers = $_POST['offers'];
        $link = $_POST['link'];
        $name = $_POST['logo'];
        $q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`casino` VALUES(NULL, '$bonus', '$deposit', '$offers', '$link', '$logo', '$name', NULL)");
        if(!$q){
          echo "<font color='red'><b>There has been an error with our database! Please contact the website administrator!</b></font><br /><br />";
        } else {
          echo "<font color='green'><b>You have successfully added the casino!</b></font><br /><br />";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<font color='red'><b>There were ".count($error)." errors in your form:</b></font><br />";
        foreach($error as $err){
          echo "<b>".$err."</b><br />";
        }
        echo "<br />";
      }
    }
```

Structure of Database:
[image]

If you need more information just let me know!

By the way, the way I know the error is in the query is because I checked if(!$q) and made it display an error message if the query can't be done, and it displays the error message on the page.

Any ideas why its not working? Also I left out date from the query because I don't know how to add the current date:time into the query.

If anyone could help with either of these issues please let me know! :)

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injections.

Comment: But we're not allowed to know what the error message said?

Comment: Save your query to a string and print it out.

Comment: I assume your query method is in a function file. Is it working? 
Btw, I find your insert query weird looking. Why not try it like this: 

      query("INSERT INTO table(row1, row1, row2, row3) VALUES ($row1, $row2, $row3)");

Comment: Hopefully you really have your `new mysqli()` function on a separate, secure page.

Comment: Your database structure does not allow for `NULL` values. Also, your `$error` variable is always going to be empty, therefore if you already have values in your table, this will cause a problem, using `INSERT`.

Comment: @PHPGlue, I don't understand at all. Strawberry, re-read my post please. Marciano, I tried that, for some reason it didn't work. Arkascha, I realize that its just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you set `NULL` the date column. Try `NOW()` instead of `NULL`:

```
$q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`casino` VALUES(NULL, '$bonus', '$deposit', '$offers', '$link', '$logo', '$name', NOW())");
```

Comment: Ok but you can't put `NULL` at a `datetime` column. Maybe you should put the keys into your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your error here is isn't very clear. Here are some debugging options you can try:

**Name the fields**

```
 $q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`casino` VALUES(NULL, '$bonus', '$deposit', '$offers', '$link', '$logo', '$name', NULL)");
```

to

```
 $q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`casino`(field1, field2...) VALUES(NULL, '$bonus', '$deposit', '$offers', '$link', '$logo', '$name', NULL)");
```

**Save your query to a string and print it out. (Gordon Linoff)**

```
echo "INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`casino` VALUES(NULL, '$bonus', '$deposit', '$offers', '$link', '$logo', '$name', NULL)"
```

before the query. This can show you what PHP is making for MySQL to feed on.

**Check for errors**

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { //check connection error
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); //check query error
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, this didn't help me sadly, I tried the new query you showed me but that didn't work. I then moved on to check for errors and it doesn't actually output any errors.